# Finding all the overlapping groups of dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy

Say I have a dictionary of lists in Python. I would like to find **all** the groups of keys that have items in common, and for each such group, the corresponding items.

For example, assuming that the items are simple integers:

```
dct      = dict()
dct['a'] = [0, 5, 7]
dct['b'] = [1, 2, 5]
dct['c'] = [3, 2]
dct['d'] = [3]
dct['e'] = [0, 5]
```

The groups would be:

```
groups    = dict()
groups[0] = ['a', 'e']
groups[1] = ['b', 'c']
groups[2] = ['c', 'd']
groups[3] = ['a', 'b', 'e']
```

And the elements in common for those groups would be:

```
common    = dict()
common[0] = [0, 5]
common[1] = [2]
common[2] = [3]
common[3] = [5]
```

To solve this problem, I believe that there is value in building a matrix like the one below, but I am not sure how to proceed from this point. Are there any Python libraries that facilitate solving this type of problem?

```
   | a  b  c  d  e |
|a|  x           x |
|b|     x  x     x |
|c|     x  x  x    |
|d|        x  x    |
|e|  x  x        x |
```

### Update

I tried to wrap up the solution that @NickBurns provided within a function, but I am having problems reproducing the solution:

```
dct = { 'a' : [0, 5, 7], 'b' : [1, 2, 5], 'c' : [3, 2], 'd' : [3], 'e' : [0, 5]}

groups, common_items = get_groups(dct)
print 'Groups', groups
print 'Common items',  common_items
```

I get:

```
Groups: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['a', 'e'], 2: ['c', 'b'], 3: ['c', 'd'], 5: ['a', 'b', 'e']})                                                        

Common items: {0: None, 2: None, 3: None, 5: None}
```

And here are the functions

```
from collections import defaultdict
def common(query_group, dct):
    """ Recursively find the common elements within groups """
    if len(query_group) <= 1:
        return
    # Extract the elements from groups,
    # Pull their original values from dct
    # Get the intersection of these
    first, second = set(dct[query_group[0]]), set(dct[query_group[1]])  
    # print(first.intersection(second))
    return common(query_group[2:], dct)


def get_groups (dct):
  groups = defaultdict(list)

  for key, values in dct.items():
    for value in values:
      groups[value].append(key)

  # Clean up the groups:      
  for key in groups.keys():
    # i.e. the value is common to more than 1 group
    if len(groups[key]) <= 1:    
      del groups[key]

  # Identify common elements:
  common_items = dict()
  for k,v in groups.iteritems():
    if len(v) > 1:
      common_items[k] = common(v, dct)

  return groups, common_items
```

Comment: Looks like a graph problem, check out the [`NetworkX`](http://networkx.github.io/) library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to create a second dictionary (`groups`) that represents the intersection of each list in the original `dct`. For example, youu could do this using a defaultdict something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
groups = defaultdict(list)
dct = { 'a' : [0, 5, 7], 'b' : [1, 2, 5], 'c' : [3, 2], 'd' : [3], 'e' : [0, 5]}
for key, values in dct.items():
    for value in values:
        groups[value].append(key)

for key in groups.keys():
    if len(groups[key]) > 1:    # i.e. the value is common to more than 1 group
        print(key, groups[key])

(0, ['a', 'e'])
(2, ['c', 'b'])
(3, ['c', 'd'])
(5, ['a', 'b', 'e'])
```

Finding the common elements is a little messier, you need to run through each group and find the intersection from the original `dct`. Perhaps a recursive routine like this would work:

```
def common(query_group, dct, have_common=[]):
    """ Recursively find the common elements within groups """

    if len(query_group) <= 1:
        return have_common

    # extract the elements from groups, and pull their original values from dct
    # then get the intersection of these
    first, second = set(dct[query_group[0]]), set(dct[query_group[1]])
    have_common.extend(first.intersection(second))

    return common(query_group[2:], dct, have_common)

for query_group in groups.values():
    if len(query_group) > 1:
        print(query_group, '=>', common(query_group, dct, have_common=[]))

['e', 'a'] => [0, 5]    
['b', 'c'] => [2]    
['d', 'c'] => [3]    
['e', 'b', 'a'] => [5}]
```

Clearly it needs some prettier formatting, but I think it gets the job done. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! Any thoughts on how to find the elements that those groups have in common? (part of the OP) Is it easy with this code?

Comment: Thanks @NickBurns. I managed to run your example, but when I try to put things together in a function (as opposed to printing the solution) I am running into errors (see my Update in the OP). Do you know why?

Comment: Oh yeah - sorry, I guess it my fault really. I left the common() function quite sloppy, because it doesn't return anything. Instead will have to keep track of the recursive calls and return their results. I will update

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty close to what you're asking for - take a look at it, and see if it's close enough.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = dict()
dct['a'] = [0, 5, 7]
dct['b'] = [1, 2, 5]
dct['c'] = [3, 2]
dct['d'] = [3]
dct['e'] = [0, 5]

inverseDict = defaultdict(list)
for key in dct:
    for item in dct[key]:
        inverseDict[item].append(key)
for item in inverseDict.keys():
    if len(inverseDict[item]) < 2:
        del inverseDict[item]

for item in inverseDict:
    print item, ":", inverseDict[item]
```

Output:

```
0 : ['a', 'e']
2 : ['c', 'b']
3 : ['c', 'd']
5 : ['a', 'b', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts  on how to find the elements that those groups have in common?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean - you see that to the left of ['a', 'e'] is a `0`, which is the element that 'a' and 'e' have in common, as is `2` for 'c' and 'b', and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) library to get that matrix(Adjacency matrix) representation:

```
import networkx as nx
dct = { 'a' : [0, 5, 7], 'b' : [1, 2, 5], 'c' : [3, 2], 'd' : [3], 'e' : [0, 5]}
nodes = sorted(dct)

G = nx.Graph()
for node in nodes:
    attached_nodes = dct[node]
    G.add_node(node)
    for nod in attached_nodes:
        if 0 <= nod < len(nodes):
            G.add_edge(node, nodes[nod])

print G.nodes()
print G.edges()
print G.has_edge('a','b')
print G.has_edge('b','c')
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd']
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'e'), ('c', 'c'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'b'), ('d', 'd')]
False
True
```

Comment: Thanks Aswhwini. This helps. Any thoughts on how to get the actual groups from this point?

Comment: I don't think the link works (at least not when I tried it), what about this one http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.6rc1/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a big mess, but it works. It is basically building an array like this:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 |
  +-----------------+
|a| 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 |
|b| 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 |
|c| 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 |
|d| 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 |
|e| 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 |
```

The groups are the unique columns with more than one `1`. To find all common elements to a group, you find the columns that have `1`s in the places where the group definition has `1`s. And writing it in Python, with a hacky use of scipy's sparse matrices to build the above array, I got the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

dct = {'a' : [0, 5, 7], 'b' : [1, 2, 5], 'c' : [3, 2],
       'd' : [3], 'e' : [0, 5]}

keys = []
lens = []
vals = []

for key, items in dct.items():
    keys.append(key)
    lens.append(len(items))
    vals.extend(items)

keys = np.array(keys)
lens = np.array(lens)
vals = np.array(vals)
unique_values, val_idx = np.unique(vals, return_inverse=True)

data = np.ones_like(val_idx)
indices = val_idx
indptr = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(lens)))

dct_array = sps.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))
dct_array = dct_array.T.toarray()
mask = dct_array.sum(axis=-1) >= 2
dct_array = dct_array[mask].astype(np.bool)
unique_values = unique_values[mask]

dct_array = np.ascontiguousarray(dct_array)
dct_array = dct_array.view((np.void,
                            (dct_array.dtype.itemsize *
                             len(keys)))).ravel()
groups, grp_idx = np.unique(dct_array,
                            return_index=True)
groups = groups.view(np.bool).reshape(-1, len(keys))
dct_array = dct_array.view(np.bool).reshape(-1, len(keys))

for group, idx in zip(groups, grp_idx) :
    print 'group {0}'.format(keys[group])
    common = unique_values[np.all(np.logical_and(dct_array[idx],
                                                 dct_array) ==
                                  dct_array[idx], axis=-1)]
    print 'common {0}'.format(common)
```

This prints out:

```
group ['c' 'd']
common [3]
group ['c' 'b']
common [2]
group ['a' 'e']
common [0 5]
group ['a' 'b' 'e']
common [5]
```