# Finding the sets of columns/rows that overlap

Tags: python, numpy

**Background**: This question takes the problem in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178504/finding-all-the-overlapping-groups-of-dictionary-keys) a step further.

Say I have a 2D array, where the columns are partitioned into several sets. For simplicity, we can assume the array holds `int` values like the following:

```
np.random.randint(3,size=(2,10))   

# Column indices:
#       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9                     
array([[0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0]])
```

As an example of a partitioning of the column indices, we can choose the following:

```
# Partitioning the column indices of the previous array:

my_partition['first']  = [0,1,2]
my_partition['second'] = [3,4]
my_partition['third']  = [5,6,7]
my_partition['fourth'] = [8, 9]
```

I would like to find the groups of sets of column indices that have columns with identical values. In the example above, some examples of these groups would be:

```
# The following sets include indices for a common column vector with values [2,0]^T
group['a'] = ['first', 'fourth'] 

# The following sets include indices for a common column vector with values [1,1]^T
group['b'] = ['second', 'third', 'fourth']
```

I am interested in a solution to this problem that works with an array holding **real** values (e.g. the values `1.0/2` and `1.0/2` are identical, i.e `1.0/2 == 1.0/2` returns `True`).

I am aware of the potential limitations of floating precision, so for simplicitly I am treating this problem in two steps:

1. Assuming that two columns are the same if the values are identical
2. Assuming that two columns are the same if the values are close to each other (e.g the vector difference is below a threshold)

I am trying to generalize the solution in the previous thread, but I am not sure if it is directly applicable. I think it would work for the first problem (fully identical values in the columns), but we may need "a bigger boat" for the second one.

Comment: Your description is confusing. I don't understand how the first and fourth columns have `[2,0]^T`. The first column looks like `[2,1]^T`, but the fourth has `[1,1]^T`.

Comment: @EMS I added more comments. Let me know if that is still not clear.

Comment: The floating point thing can be tricky... Imagine you set a threshold for equality of 0.001. Now imagine partition `A` has item `[2.0, 0.0]`, partition `B` has `[2.0009, 0.0]` and partition `C` has item `[2.0011, 0.0]`. Do you want to create a single group with `A`, `B` and `C`? Or would you rather have two groups, `A` and `B`, and `B` and `C`?

Comment: Yes, it is still not clear. The column with index 1 has value `[2,1]^T` and the column with index 4 has value `[1,1]^T`. It makes the part "group[a] = ['first', 'fourth']" hard to understand because neither of those columns has value `[2,0]^T`.

Comment: It seems you are saying that you are given an arbitrary set of pre-defined groups of columns. And for each pair of the pre-defined groups, you want to know if those groups contain a column in common.

Comment: @Jaime. I am looking for all groups, i.e. in your case, the groups would be `A,B`, `B,C`, and `A, B, C` unless they all hold **same** columns, no more, no less (i.e. the set difference of these sets of columns is fully empty) in which case, the group should be `A,B,C`.

Comment: But the tricky part is `A,B,C`, because although all 3 are within `0.001` of a common vector, `A` and `C` are not within `0.001` of each other. Detecting `A,B,C` is going to be hard, I believe.

Comment: With the issue of tolerances aside, I think the update to my answer might at least provide the logical part of the algorithm needed. No claims whatsoever that it is an efficient approach.

Comment: How large are these arrays? A numpy solution is likely not optimal unless the arrays are much larger then shown.

Comment: @Ophion. The arrays are ~(1000, 1000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a set-style data structure out of the collection of columns, here is one way to do it (I'm sure there are more efficient ways for larger data):

```
group = {}
for i in range(array.shape[1]):
    tup = tuple(array[:,i])
    if tup in group.keys():
        group[tup].append(i)
    else:
        group[tup] = [i]
```

Executed for your example of `array` gives:

```
In [132]: group
Out[132]:
{(0, 1): [0],
 (0, 2): [6],
 (1, 0): [5],
 (1, 1): [4, 7, 8],
 (2, 0): [2, 9],
 (2, 1): [1, 3]}
```

Since `numpy.ndarray` is (like `list`) not hashable, the columns can't serve as the `dict` key themselves. I chose to just use the `tuple`-equivalent of the column, but there are many other choices.

Also, I assume that a `list` of the column indices is desired in `group`. If this is really true, you could consider using a `defaultdict` instead of a regular `dict`. But you can also use many other containers for storing the column indices.

**Updated**

I believe I understand better what the question is asking: Given an arbitrary collection of pre-defined groups of columns, how to determine whether any two given groups contain a column in common.

If we assume you have already built the set-like structure in my answer above, you can take the two groups, look at their constituent columns, and ask if any columns wind up being in the same part of the set dictionary:

Suppose we define:

```
my_partition['first']  = [0,1,2]
my_partition['second'] = [3,4]
my_partition['third']  = [5,6,7]
my_partition['fourth'] = [8, 9]

# Define a helper to back-out the column that serves as a key for the set-like structure.
# Take 0th element, column index should only be part of one subset.
get_key = lambda x: [k for k,v in group.iteritems() if x in v][0]

# use itertools
import itertools

# Print out the common columns between each pair of groups.
for pair_x, pair_y in itertools.combinations(my_partition.keys(), 2):
    print pair_x, pair_y, (set(map(get_key, my_partition[pair_x])) &
                           set(map(get_key, my_partition[pair_y])))
```

Whenever that's not the empty set, it means some columns were in common between the two groups.

Executed for your problem:

```
In [163]: for pair_x, pair_y in itertools.combinations(my_partition.keys(), 2):
    print pair_x, pair_y, set(map(get_key, my_partition[pair_x])) & set(map(get_key, my_partition[pair_y]))
   .....:
second fourth set([(1, 1)])
second third set([(1, 1)])
second first set([(2, 1)])
fourth third set([(1, 1)])
fourth first set([(2, 0)])
third first set([])
```